# How to only apply preferred color scheme to one view and not the rest of the views in the view hierarchy in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to make one view render in dark mode while the rest of my app is in the users chosen color scheme. When I apply `.preferredColorScheme(.dark)` to the subview, it causes other views to turn dark as well. How can I fix this behavior?

**ContentView:**

```
NavigationView {
    ZStack {
        NavigationLink(isActive: $showingGoalDashboardView) {
            TestView(goal: goals.first!)
        } label: {
            EmptyView()
        }
                
        NavigationLink(isActive: $showingCreateGoalView) {
            CreateGoalView(showingGoalCreateView: $showingCreateGoalView)
        } label: {
            EmptyView()
        }
                
        LoadingView()
    }
}
```

**LoadingView:**
LoadingView just contains some UI elements, all wrapped in a `ZStack` with the property `.preferredColorScheme(.dark)` applied to it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
LoadingView()
    .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `preferredColorScheme` works NOT per-view, but *for current presentation* - which in this case is a current window. See documentation:

[image: demo]

Put `LoadingView` into sheet or popover, or new window, etc, and there dark mode will be applied independently.

Update: well, actually it can still be used `View.colorScheme`, and it works, but it has been deprecated - just be aware:

```
    LoadingView()
        .colorScheme(.dark)
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Comment: This doesn't override the system's color scheme setting. The system's setting takes preference